# Richt Text Editor in Objective-C / iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, editor, rtf

I'm currently using a UIWebView as RTF-Editor, but that method seems to be a little bit "laggy" and not very stable. Is there a better way to achieve a RTF-Editor in iOS?
Are there any libraries out there? I've searched in google, but haven't found a lot...

Thanks,
Lukas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CoreText or just wait for iOS6, which will have attributed strings in nearly all UIKit controls

Comment: Unfortunately these are the only two options.  I am also forced to use UIWebView for the time being....le sigh.

Comment: hi ok, thanks for the responde. I think i will wait till iOS6 arrives.